# Django stacktrace not informative

Tags: python, django, debugging, stack-trace

When I have a bug in Django, the stacktrace usually showed only Django's internal
files, not my application files (usually view.py,..) that caused the bug.

How can I make Django show me the full stacktrace?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: It should be showing the entire stacktrace, although sometimes the error in your files is hidden way low down in the log. A helpful thing I realized recently is that Django bolds your errors in DEBUG mode

Comment: Without meaning to be snarky, are you sure you're reading the full stacktrace?